# Copying .config Sections: Null Ref

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have a .exe that points to two other .config files (NOT the .exe of the running .config).  .config1 is the source and .config2 is the target.  I want to copy a section that is present in .config1 into .config2.  When I use this code:

```
targetConfig.Sections.Add("newSection", sourceSection);
targetConfig.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
```

I get an null ref, even though when I traverse the graph in both the source and the target, everything looks instantiated.

When I follow the MSDN docs about how to use the .Add method in context of thethe .OpenMappedExeConfig method found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationmanager.openmappedexeconfiguration?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Configuration_ConfigurationManager_OpenMappedExeConfiguration_System_Configuration_ExeConfigurationFileMap_System_Configuration_ConfigurationUserLevel_), it creates a new class in code.  When I do that, the insert works fine.  Has anyone else run into this issue?

Comment: What line throws the exception? Is `targetConfig` null? `targetConfig.Sections`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

I was incorrect, it was this exception
Message = "Cannot add a ConfigurationSection that already belongs to the Configuration."

and this is the answer:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/55727833-32e5-485a-ba8c-9c6db7e82e81/configurationadd-throws-exception?forum=vblanguage